Freezing and boiling point of water
What is the exact boiling and freezing point of water? Is it $\pu{273 K}$ or $\pu{273.15K}$ and $\pu{373 K}$ or $\pu{373.15 K}$? I am a bit confused as my Chemistry NCERT class-12 part-1 textbook says $373.15$ and $273.0$

I know that we add $273.15$ to convert to $\pu{K}$ so why is the number $0.15$ not appearing in freezing point but appearing in boiling point? Can someone please explain?
Also another question if the triple point of water is $\pu{273.16 K}$ why we use $\pu{273.15}$ as the conversion scale for degree to kelvin why not $273.16$? What is the reason for this?

Welcome to Chemistry SE site! It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that.
Searching domains stackexchange.com, wikipedia.org and optionally libretexts.org is assumed as prerequisite before asking.//Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

The absolute temperature of standard melting and boiling points of water is $\pu{273.15 K}$ and $\pu{373.15 K}$.
The values $273$ and $373$, e.g. in subscripts/superscripts, are often used as a shortcut to the above, similarly as $298$ for $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$.
Triple point of water is defined (as the Kelvin scale definition until 2019) at $\pu{273.16 K}$, resp. $\pu{+0.01 ^\circ C}$
Note that the definition of Kelvin unit is detached from water triple point (influenced by isotopic composition, in last years referring to the mean oceanic water standard) since 2019.
It is currently defined by the exact definition value of the Boltzmann constant $k_\text{B} = \pu{1.380649E−23 J K−1}$. But the difference is negligible for all common practical purposes.
